# Table with one record

Tags: sql

Is there an object to store single value describing database? I need to store 
"expiration date" of my database. Should I create table with single value? Have SQL another way to store single data?

Comment: I think the question is what are you going to do with that data point? Also, any answer will likely be product specific, so please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60819569/edit) your question, add a tag for the specific database product that you're using, and add some context to the question. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Why do you think a table with a single column and single row isn't suitable?

Comment: Yes, I used table with single column and single row, but I wonder if  it is more suitable object.